# file encoding and deformed strings

Tags: encoding, malformed

I am just working with a text file, that contains lots of deformed strings such as:

```
VyplÅ<88>te prosÃ­m pole "jmÃ©no
```

My editor says that the file encoding is latin1. The string is supposed to be a czech sentence that contains some diacritics so no wonder it is displayed wrong. I have tried to force utf8 and latin2 encodings in my editor but that did not help. I have also tried to use iconv to convert the file from latin1 to utf8 or latin2 but neither that helped. I quite often encounter issues likes this and I don't know any other solution than to manually rewrite the strings. Is there a better way to fix this?

**EDIT:**

Here is the original sentence:

```
Vyplňte prosím pole "jméno"
```

Here is hex dump of the part where the malformed string occurs:

```
0002640: 6a6d 656e 6f22 5d20 3d20 2744 453a 2056  jmeno"] = 'DE: V
0002650: 7970 6cc5 8874 6520 7072 6f73 c3ad 6d20  ypl..te pros..m 
0002660: 706f 6c65 2022 6a6d c3a9 6e6f 222e 273b  pole "jm..no".';
```

**EDIT2:**

The sentence above is really correct utf8 as deceze have said. But I have just found out some strange thing. If I try to transcode the file from utf8 to utf8 (with iconv), I get an error on a word: `Postgebühr` at character `ü`. If I look at hex dump, this character is represented as `\xfc` (252 in decimal), which is valid latin1 byte encoding for `ü` but completely invalid utf8 byte encoding. It seems that part of the file is in latin1 and another part in utf8. Here is part of the file that is in latin1 (probably):

```
0000250: 506f 7374 6765 62fc 6872 273b 0a09 0963  Postgeb.hr';...c
0000260: 6f6e 665b 2277 6166 6572 7322 5d20 3d20  onf["wafers"] = 
0000270: 2744 453a 206f 706c c3a1 746b 20c3 273b  'DE: opl..tk .';
```

As I look into this more, this even does not seem to be valid latin1 cause even in latin1 it is garbled (`DE: oplÃ¡tk Ã` instead of probably `DE: oplatky za`). This part of the file seems to contain some damaged text.

I can't understand how encoding in this file could have got mixed up like that. Any ideas?

Comment: And what text is supposed to be there?

Comment: It should be: Vyplňte prosím pole "jméno"

Comment: That's UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is *supposed to contain Latin2 encoded text*, then trying to convert it *from Latin1* or similar is of course messing things up.

The problem is simply that your text editor does not automagically recognize the encoding, since the single-byte Latin* encodings all look identically interchangeable on a byte level. If your editor "tells" you the encoding is Latin1, what it means is that it is currently *interpreting* the file as Latin1. Obviously it has that wrong.

You either need to tell your editor to treat the file as Latin2 (Open As... Latin2, or however your editor gives you this choice) or to convert the file from Latin2 into an encoding your editor handles correctly.

To understand encodings better, I recommend you read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

---

In response to your posted hex dump: That file *is* UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: "You either need to tell your editor to treat the file as Latin2" - I have tried that.
"convert the file from Latin2 into an encoding your editor handles correctly" - conversion from latin2 to utf8 did not help.

Comment: Then figure out what the byte values in the file are (use a hex editor) and what characters *should* be there and try to find what encoding it really is. Post some sample data here for help with that.

Comment: "supposed to contain Latin2 encoded text" - I have edited my post to be more clear. I don't know the original encoding, I just know what characters should be there (some with diacritics).

Comment: If the file is utf-8 encoded, what causes the garbage characters to occur?

Comment: The editor incorrectly interpreting it as Latin1 instead of UTF-8.

Comment: I have tried to force utf-8 encoding in my editor. This is not the cause.

Comment: Also why should it interpret wrong, if it is regular utf8 text?

Comment: Please read the article I linked to if you want an in-depth explanation. In short: your editor gets it wrong, because the encoding of plain-text files is nowhere declared and its guessing capabilities are apparently flawed. When you "force UTF-8", you're probably telling it to *save the file as UTF-8* instead of forcing it to *reinterpret the file as UTF-8*. Depends on your editor.

Comment: Well my editor is vim, and what i am doing is `:set encoding=utf8`, which does not help. In vim latin1 encoding is used, when the encoding could not be detected which is likely here. And iconv from utf8 to utf8 gives an error like: iconv: illegal input sequence at position 599. So I don't think it is an issue of incorrect interpretation. Rather there is something wrong in the file.

Comment: But thanks for the link to that article. Useful read. Based on it, I guess the data in the file cannot be recovered.

Comment: I don't know vim too well, but if you're using it on the command line there may be a secondary issue of vim getting it correct but your terminal misinterpreting the output of vim.

Comment: Well, you were right about that sentence being encoded correctly in utf8. The thing is, at the beginning of the file, there seems to be text in some other encoding (probably latin1). The file contains text of two different encodings which causes the issue. Strange.

Comment: Well, it seems the file *effed up* then; and that's the technical term for it. If it really contains mixed encodings you're pretty screwed.

Answer (score 0):

Iconv is the way to go, but you must know the correct enconding. Latin2 (iso8859-2) is only one of the possibilities, since there were many ascii extensions in Europe. What language is this supposed to be in?

Comment: You can then also try with CP1250.